# What's the difference between a "Socialize" and a "Socialize!" activity?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've noticed activities like socializing or meditating appearing in the unit list in different colors: either in green, or in magenta with an exclamation mark. What's the difference between the two?

[image]

Comment: Is one of them on fire? :o. That's usually what exclamation marks mean =p (Though not in this case I think)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The green one is an activity they do when they don't have other activities.
>
> The magenta one is the satisfaction of an important need for the dwarf, and they will keep at it until they are satisfied above other things.

[Source](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=154406.0)

The magenta one will not be cancelled for a job. The green one will be cancelled for a job.[Found here](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?PHPSESSID=4d08fa8b7c8f0353bc88af9acff6196a&topic=154206.msg6638314#msg6638314)